# Iterate dictionary with eval strange behavior

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I have this python function:

```
def evaluate_corr_level(corr):

    corr_table= {
    eval("corr == 0"):"No correlation", 
    eval("corr > 0 and corr <= 0.3"):"Weak correlation", 
    eval("corr > 0.3 and corr <= 0.7"): "Moderate correlation",
    eval("corr > 0.7"): "Strong correlation",
    eval("corr < 0 and corr >= -0.3"): "Weak inverse correlation",
    eval("corr < 0.3 and corr >= -0.7"): "Moderate inverese correlation",
    eval("corr < -0.7"): "Strong inverse correlation"
    }

    for k, val in corr_table.items():
        print(k,val)
```

If I pass 0.5 as a parameter I get printed:

```
False Strong inverse correlation
True Moderate correlation
```

Which is not what I expected. What's wrong with the code?
I assume it's some string to float issue (not very familiar with eval())

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Print something if `corr` is within a specific range? Why use a dict in the first place? A simple `if...elif...` is all you need.

Comment: I was experimenting how to implement a switch case in python. Yes, if statement does the job (better)! Thanks!

Comment: And why are you bothering with `eval`? There's no distinction between what you have and the same code with all instances of `eval("` and the matching `")` deleted (except your code is significantly slower). And even if you managed to make this work, redefining the `dict` on every call saves nothing; you end up unconditionally evaluating all conditions, with no short-circuiting.

Comment: "Which is obviously not right" what is *obviously* not right about it? dict keys must be *unique*. Also, as pointed out `eval` does nothing useful here, it only slows down and obfuscates your code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand it now. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you want to `eval` on demand.  I think you'd be better off using lambda functions.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco or any functions, but how would that work in a dict? The OP really just needs to use `if..elif..else`

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained why this doesn't work as you expect. I'll explain why what you're trying to do is wrong and how to fix it. The main problem here is that getting `switch`-like performance in Python only works if the `dict` can be defined ahead of time; if you define it on every function call, you do all the work of an entire `if/elif/else` chain without the ability to short-circuit, and with unnecessary temporaries, making it worse than just the naïve approach (which I slightly optimized by reordering to get only 0-1 tests per condition, not 1-2):

```
if corr < -0.7:
    x = "Strong inverse correlation"
elif corr < -0.3:
    x = "Moderate inverse correlation"
elif corr < 0:
    x = "Weak inverse correlation"
elif corr == 0:
    x = "No correlation"
elif corr <= 0.3:
    x = "Weak correlation"
elif corr <= 0.7:
    x = "Moderate correlation"
else:
    x = "Strong correlation"
```

If you want to optimize this for `switch` like behavior, you need to define a `dict` outside the function once, in a way that you can reuse it every time (so you only pay a `O(1)` lookup cost, not a `O(n)` `dict` building cost as well). It's tricky to do this with `float`s and probably not worth it, though in this particular case it's technically doable:

```
import math

rounding_table = (math.floor, math.ceil)  # Look up with val >= 0, so floor used for negative, ceil for others

corr_table = {
    **dict.fromkeys(range(-7, -3), "Moderate inverse correlation"),
    **dict.fromkeys(range(-3, 0), "Weak inverse correlation"),
    0: "No correlation",
    **dict.fromkeys(range(1, 4), "Weak correlation"),
    **dict.fromkeys(range(4, 8), "Moderate correlation"),
    }

def evaluate_corr_level(corr):
    # Multiply by 10 and round away from 0 to get normalized integer form matching our table's keys
    norm_corr_key = rounding_table[corr >= 0](corr * 10)

    try:
        # Look up anything that rounded to a value in the table cheaply
        return corr_table[norm_corr_key]
    except KeyError:
        # If it's outside the range -0.7 - 0.7, it's a strong correlation, sign
        # tells us if it's inverse or not
        return "Strong inverse correlation" if corr < 0 else "Strong correlation"
```

In theory, this replaces 1-6 conditional tests with 2-3 (for sign, the implicit test for "is it in the table" and the possible third test for sign if it isn't). But both table lookups, the multiplication by 10, and the rounding step are, while relatively fixed cost, largely more expensive than simple numeric tests.

To be clear, this is almost certainly not justified; it probably won't produce performance improvements in real code unless the number of ranges is larger (if the `if/elif/else` chain has 30 unique cases, it might help, at the expense of a potentially larger lookup table, but for seven, probably not). And it only works because there was a semi-reasonable way to normalize the `float` inputs to a small range of `int`s; if the ranges involved tests for values out to the 10th decimal place, the size of the required `dict` would be ridiculous.

Alternatively, for the `float` case, you could use a range-based pre-built lookup table in sorted order and search it in `O(log n)` time with the `bisect` module:

```
import bisect
import math

# Make table that will consistently follow rules from tests when used with
# bisect.bisect, including distinguishing 0 from just above 0
# Must construct it outside function to avoid rebuilding it every time (we need math.nextafter to get the system's next larger value, so non-literals get involved)
corr_table = (-0.7, -0.3, 0, math.nextafter(0, math.inf), math.nextafter(0.3, math.inf), math.nextafter(0.7, math.inf))

def evaluate_corr_level(corr):
    # Get index into table of strings in O(log n) time
    index = bisect.bisect(corr_table, corr)

    # This table is a tuple of constant literals, so we can use it inline,
    # and Python uses a constant tuple without rebuilding it
    # Actual lookup is O(1)
    return ("Strong inverse correlation", "Moderate inverse correlation", "Weak inverse correlation", "No correlation", "Weak correlation", "Moderate correlation", "Strong correlation")[index]
```

That's more practical for arbitrary floats. It may not save anything in this case (again, seven distinct cases isn't *that* much) but it's likely to lose by less since it doesn't need to normalize the input, and therefore has lower fixed overhead and might win sooner than the `dict` table (while also avoiding explosions in memory usage that the `dict` requires for more and more precise floats).

Answer (score 2):

When you defined your dictionary, you are evaluating your conditions to be `True`s and `False`s to be the keys. However, in a dictionary, keys are unique, so all declarations of `False/True` but the last stays (they get overwritten).

Comment: Makes sense! Also have a lack of dictionary knowledge apparently... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary can only have one of each distinct key. Since you are using eval() for the keys, it will either return `True` or `False` (there can only be a maximum of two keys in this dictionary)

Because of this, eval() will override the previous same key. It is always printing out the last two key:value pairs because they have the keys `True` and `False`, which override all previous `True` and `False` keys

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy as a replacement of a switch case:

```
import numpy as np

def evaluate_corr_level(corr,bins):
    statements = ("Strong inverse correlation","Moderate inverse correlation",
                  "Weak inverse correlation","No correlation","weak correlation",
                  "Moderate correlation","Strong correlation"
                  )
    return statements[np.searchsorted(bins, corr,side='right')]

eps=np.finfo(np.float).eps
bins_corr = np.array([-0.7, -0.3, 0,eps, 0.3+eps, 0.7+eps])

print(evaluate_corr_level(0.71,bins_corr))
```

Comment: Ooh, while it requires `numpy`, this is, theoretically, a much better solution than mine. Up-voted.

Comment: It did inspire me to add a similar solution using Python builtins (`bisect` module), which made me notice a slight flaw in your code; it can't distinguish `corr == 0` from `0 < corr <= 0.3` (you always say "No correlation" in that case), and it is effectively testing `< 0.3` and `< 0.7` instead of `<= 0.3` and `<= 0.7` as in the OP's code. Both problems are fixable (see my solution's `math.nextafter`; `numpy` may have a better approach). You'd also want to define `bins` outside the function so it's not repeatedly rebuilt (`statements` can be inside the function if it's changed to a `tuple`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are right! I forgot the weak correlation. Should be fixed now, including the edge cases. What is the advantage of making `statements` a tuple ?

Comment: If it's a `list`, the (incredibly limited) optimizer has no way to know it won't be modified, so it stores the constant values of the `list`, but has to load them one by one and then build a new `list` every time you invoke the function. If it's a constant `tuple` of constant literals, it's 100% immutable, so it builds it once at compile time, shoves it in the function constants, and loading it in the future is a single instruction that produces a single array lookup, with no allocations made (vs. the `list`, that loads seven things & builds a new `list`, allocating the new `list` every time).